# Rights of UK police home visit, no warrant

Tags: united-kingdom, police

Police turned up at the door the other day and were unfortunately let in by my very distressed mother before I got to the door (I would have checked warrant, ID etc through door first). My brother and I went to help our mum and after we ascertained there was no warrant, or clear reason for entry, asked them to leave. They refused and we asked several more times, but still refused. With hindsight I should have called their superior but was wondering was that legal for them to remain in the property despite 2 occupants who would not have let them in asking them to leave? My mother is elderly and could not make that decision, in shock, herself rationally.

Comment: *My mother is elderly and could not make that decision, in shock, herself rationally* Is your mother legally incapacitated?

Comment: Your mother gave the police permission to enter the property, so on the face of it they entered legally. You do not say why they were there or why they refused to leave when asked. Did they not say why they were there or anything along such lines?

Comment: Shall we assume this is her house and you were visitors? Usually, a property owner has pretty absolute authority to let people in.

Comment: @user6726 I think it would be the legal occupant. In case I'm renting a house, I don't think the property owner can usually just let the police in. Might be wrong.

Comment: I have sufficient confidence in the British police, and as I have absolutely nothing whatsoever to hide from them, that any police officer is welcome in my home at any hour of the day or night, with or without a warrant. And I would provide them with any information they required in the course of their duty. Furthermore I would ask them if they would like a cup of tea.